# x and y can be no greater than 2D, in the graph

Tags: tensorflow, keras-2

fixing an error ValueError: x and y can be no greater than 2-D, but have shapes (23,) and (23, 12, 1) and to make my original graph with prediction graph line

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reshape`

```
a = np.random.random(size=(23, 12, 1))
a.shape   #(23, 12, 1)

#Reshape
a = a.reshape((23,12))
a.shape   #(23,12)
```

Let us know if the issue still persists. Thanks!